# How to query from URL "Line" Format to VBA variable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba, lines

I'm trying to make an application that will display user data through api on command...  I have assembled the URL generator and everything. it's just beyond me to find a simple way to assign THIS: "http://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=xbox&name=charlie%20is%20tftc&output=lines" data to specific variables with my parameters. (Lines / Text format)

This is my code so far, I just want to be able to assign data like 'player.id' to playerid and display it. (Player.id is the first value in the data linked above)

//the code below will be changed to user input, I don't need help with that this was just for theory

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub URL_Player_Info(ByVal Address As String)

    'Assign all data figures for constructing the "URL"...
    Dim url, plat, player, webprefix, domain, paramsym, ext, preplat, preplayer, andsym, lineparam, format As String

    'Variables for "Plat"
    plat = "xbox"

    'Input for "Player"
    player = "Charlie Is TFTC"

    'Structure for "URL"
    webprefix = "http://"
    domain = "api.bf4stats"
    ext = ".com/api/playerInfo"
    paramsym = "?"
    preplat = "plat="
    andsym = "&"
    preplayer = "name="
    format = "output="
    lineparam = "lines"

    'Generate Final "URL"
    url = webprefix + domain + ext + paramsym + preplat + plat + andsym + preplayer + player + andsym + format + lineparam

    'Getting Data / Assigning Data for "Plat. Player: Params"


End Sub
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Why are you breaking up the url into so many pieces? Is there anything other than Plat and Player you want to change?

Comment: VBA or VB.NET ?  Not the same thing...